# My ISP is adding a domain suffix .numericable.fr on my DNS resolution

Tags: networking, dns, display-resolution

With remote working due to coronavirus, I am working at home, and my local kubernetes dns resolution is failing.

when I type:

```
nslookup localhost
```

I get:

```
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
localhost.numericable.fr    canonical name = nc-ass-vip.sdv.fr.
Name:   nc-ass-vip.sdv.fr
Address: 212.95.74.75
```

and this is messing around with kubernetes dns resolution.

How should I remove the suffix .numericable.fr ( my ISP )

I am running on Ubuntu 19.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been through the exact same situation (not with kubernetes though).
The solution for me was to set the DNS manually for the wifi network concerned.

- Open Settings
- Select Wifi/Network depending on your type of connection
- Click on the settings icon of your network
- In the ipv4 tab, turn off automatic DNS
- Set the DNS values to the one of your supplier. For numericable, I've set `89.2.0.1, 89.2.0.2`.

Hope it helps !

Happy remote working and take care !

Comment: Yep, it did the trick ! Can you explain to me the problem ? I don't understand it !

Comment: Not an expert in DNS stuff, but when you connect to a network, your DNS is set automatically by this connection. Turns out, your localhost address was pointing to localhost.numericable.fr because of this automatically set 'bad' DNS. I don't know how, I don't know why...

Comment: ok ! Thanks for the explaination !